# I have a dataset and i want to make a table that consists of column a)set-which can be any serial number b)hubname c)ratio

Tags: r, for-loop

Input:

| Pincode | Original_Hubname | Active_Hubname | Pincode_demand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 238858 | AngMoKio | OrchardRoad | 10 |
| 569933 | AngMoKio | AngMoKio | 25 |
| 310145 | OrchardRoad | OrchardRoad | 20 |
| 521147 | OrchardRoad | AngMoKio | 35 |
| 520147 | Simei | Bishan | 20 |
| 570150 | Bishan | Simei | 15 |
| 310178 | Lorong | Tampine | 40 |
| 310168 | Tampine | Tampine | 10 |
| 510987 | Woodlands | Yishun | 30 |
| 510954 | Yishun | Woodlands | 25 |
| 510675 | Yishun | PasirRis | 5 |
| 510385 | PasirRis | Yishun | 30 |
| 510674 | PasirRis | PasirRis | 50 |

Required Output:

| Set | Hubname | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OrchardRoad | 0.33 |
| 1 | AngMoKio | 0.67 |
| 2 | Bishan | 0.57 |
| 2 | Simei | 0.43 |
| 3 | Lorong | 0 |
| 3 | Tampine | 1 |
| 4 | Yishun | 0.43 |
| 4 | Woodlands | 0.18 |
| 4 | PasirRis | 0.39 |

Set is not made properly through my code below and hence ratio is not being calculated correctly as well.

Rscript:

```
data<-Input
filtered_data <- subset(data, Original_Hubname != Active_Hubname)
unique_hubs <- unique(filtered_data[, c("Original_Hubname", "Active_Hubname")])
result <- data.frame(Set = integer(), Hubname = character(), Ratio = numeric(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
set_counter <- 1
for (i in 1:nrow(unique_hubs)) {
  original_hub <- unique_hubs$Original_Hubname[i]
  active_hub <- unique_hubs$Active_Hubname[i]
  original_demand <- data$pc_demand[data$Original_Hubname == original_hub]
  active_demand <- data$pc_demand[data$Active_Hubname == active_hub]
  total_demand <- sum(original_demand) + sum(active_demand)
  if (total_demand > 0) {
    ratio_original <- sum(original_demand) / total_demand
    ratio_active <- sum(active_demand) / total_demand
    if (!(original_hub %in% result$Hubname)) {
      result <- rbind(result, data.frame(Set = set_counter, Hubname = original_hub, Ratio = ratio_original))
    }
    if (!(active_hub %in% result$Hubname)) {
      result <- rbind(result, data.frame(Set = set_counter, Hubname = active_hub, Ratio = ratio_active))
    }
    set_counter <- set_counter + 1
  }
}
result <- na.omit(result)
```

The code should be able to make set of hubs between all hubs where pincode exchange has happened in between.

Expected Output:

| Set | Hubname | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OrchardRoad | 0.33 |
| 1 | AngMoKio | 0.67 |
| 2 | Bishan | 0.57 |
| 2 | Simei | 0.43 |
| 3 | Lorong | 0 |
| 3 | Tampine | 1 |
| 4 | Yishun | 0.43 |
| 4 | Woodlands | 0.18 |
| 4 | PasirRis | 0.39 |

Code Ouput:

| Set | Hubname | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AngMokio | 0.5384615385 |
| 1 | Orchard Road | 0.4615384615 |
| 3 | Simei | 0.5 |
| 3 | Bishan | 0.5 |
| 5 | Lorong | 0.4444444444 |
| 5 | Tampine | 0.5555555556 |
| 6 | Woodlands | 0.3333333333 |
| 6 | Yishun | 0.6666666667 |
| 8 | Pasir Ris | 0.6470588235 |

Comment: Welcome to SO! It makes it much easier for others to help if you include a reproducible example. Please don't share data as images - can you please edit your question to include a sample of data using `dput()`?

Comment: Yep, figured an easy way to do it.